# Doxygen won't resolve reference to typedef in namespace

Tags: c++, doxygen, typedef

Doxygen works fine with the following short example:

```
/** \file */

/// This is an integer
typedef int myInteger;

/// This is the same as \ref myInteger
typedef myInteger myOtherInteger;
```

[image]

But it won't resolve the reference to `myInteger` if I put it into a namespace.

```
/** \file */

namespace bar {

/// This is an integer
typedef int myInteger;

/// This is the same as \ref myInteger
typedef myInteger myOtherInteger;

}
```

[image]

Notice that neither of the two mentions of `myInteger` are links now.  It also complains:

> warning: unable to resolve reference to `myInteger' for \ref command

Writing `\ref bar::myInteger` does not help.

How can I fix this?

I have doxygen 1.8.13.

Comment: It seems to be related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600829), but that's marked as fixed in 1.7.0 ...

Comment: When documenting namespace bar it does work also when setting EXTRACT_ALL to YES I see the myInteger after the \ref

Comment: @albert I don't want `EXTRACT_ALL`, but documenting the namespace does indeed work. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. However, it also creates a whole new section and page for that namespace, which I would like to avoid (everything is in the same namespace anyway). Do you know if this can be done?

Comment: Regarding the namespace I think best is to look at the command "doxygen -l [layoutFileName.xml]" and modily this file and reference it in your Doxyfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the documentation properly there are some possibilities:

- document the namespace
- set EXTRACT_ALL to YES

negative aspect is that the namespace is shown as extra tab in the documentation. this can be overcome by modifying the used layout file:

- doxygen -l [layoutFileName.xml]
- modify generated file (set parts about namespace to visible="no")
- reference file in Doxyfile

Comment: I don't want to EXTRACT_ALL :(

Comment: @AdamZahran well the other option is to document the namespace.