# Doxygen references inside a template class inside a namespace

Tags: doxygen

In the following minimal example, I have a template class in a namespace. The description of each member refers to another member.

```cpp
/// @brief My namespace
namespace template_test
{

template <int param_v>
class TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /// @brief \ref template_test::TemplateClass::func2()    <- OK
    int func1() { return 1; }

    /// @brief \ref func1()                                  <- unable to resolve
    int func2() { return 2; }
};

class InstanceClass
{
    TemplateClass<5> m_templ_class;
};

} // namespace template_test
```

At this example, I get the error

> unable to resolve reference to 'func1()' for \ref command

One possible solution would be to always reference to entire signature including the namespace `template_test::TemplateClass::...` like at `func1()`. But I find this quite confusing and if you change the namespace once, you have to refactor the entire documentation.

I am particularly surprised by the following observations:

1. It works without problems if the **template class is in the main namespace**.

```cpp
template <int param_v>
class TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /// @brief \ref func2()       <- OK
    int func1() { return 1; }

    /// @brief \ref func1()       <- OK
    int func2() { return 2; }
};

/// @brief My namespace
namespace template_test
{

class InstanceClass
{
    TemplateClass<5> m_templ_class;
};

} // namespace template_test
```

2. It works without problems if **no template** is used.

```cpp
/// @brief My namespace
namespace test
{

class NoTemplateClass
{
  public:
    /// @brief \ref func2()       <- OK
    int func1() { return 1; }

    /// @brief \ref func1()       <- OK
    int func2() { return 2; }
};

class InstanceClass
{
    NoTemplateClass m_no_templ_class;
};

} // namespace test
```

How does this particular behavior occur when a template class is inside a namespace?

Is there an easier way than specifying namespace and class name for each reference?

Regarding [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845369/doxygen-wont-resolve-reference-to-typedef-in-namespace), `EXTRACT_ALL` is set to YES.

**ETA:**

As soon as I remove the

```cpp
class InstanceClass
{
    TemplateClass<5> m_templ_class;
};
```

it's possible to create the links to both functions within the `TemplateClass`.

**Difference with default Doxyfile**

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.5 (2f6875a5ca481a69a6f32650c77a667f87d25e88)
PROJECT_NAME           = ${PROJECT_NAME}
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ${DOCS_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = YES
WARN_LOGFILE           = ${DOXYGEN_WARN_LOG_FILE}
INPUT                  = ${INPUTS}
FILE_PATTERNS          = ${FILE_PATTERNS}
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = *.txt
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = _doxygen
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = ${SOURCE_DIR}/tools/doxygen/doxygen-awesome.css
USE_MATHJAX            = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = TeX/AMSmath \
                         TeX/AMSsymbols
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
XML_OUTPUT             = _doxygen/xml
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
PREDEFINED             = TSM_USE_VFC_UNITS
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = NO
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOTFILE_DIRS           = .
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = /usr/share/plantuml/plantuml.jar
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 350
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? (Necessary to see whether it is a problem with the current version or with the version you use).

Comment: I'm using Doxygen version 1.8.17.

Comment: That version is a bit older (December 27, 2019), so please update to the current version (1.9.6). I tried with the default doxygen settings except that I set `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` (as indicated) and in 1.8.17 and 1.9.6 the link to `func1()` is present. It must be something subtle, please share the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` (edit it into the question).

Comment: I did it with version 1.9.5. There I have the same behavior as described here. Unfortunately, I cannot update to the latest version in my company.

Comment: With the 1.9.5 version I see the warning but at the page classtemplate__test_1_1TemplateClass.html the links are all present (so looks like a bogus warning). or did I look at the wrong page? With the 1.9.6 version the warning is gone. With the 1.8.17 version I still don't get the warning.

Comment: OK, that's a very helpful info that the warning is gone with 1.9.6. I'll ask if we can update to 1.9.6 in our company. I can't ignore the warning because we have to set "WARN_AS_ERROR" to YES... THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: You could always install doxygen 1.9.6 locally so you can test.

Answer (score 0):

As Albert wrote in the comments, it works without warning/error with Doxygen version 1.9.6. In this respect, this is the actual solution to the problem.